# A Database for Plant Metabolome or Secondary Metabolites?

Tags: database, public-databases

I am searching for a plant metabolome or secondary metabolite database for a college bioinformatics project. Up until now, I have found these two databases, as I am giving their links below;

- http://scbt.sastra.edu/pmdb/
- https://www.plantcyc.org/https://www.plantcyc.org/

and searched for different scientific articles and reviews;

- https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpls.2013.00073/full
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27258266

But only one and updated database which could contain all known plants and all of their known metabolites would be perfect. Could you suggest me any database or any other source with a high coverage for my project?

Comment: Can you use the plant reactome db? http://plantreactome.gramene.org/

Comment: Do you really need to be all plants, and all metabolites? We don't have even for humans all the metabolites! Let alone know all plants, and from all have all the metabolites. Welcome to the site! Nice first question

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @b.nota, I will check the db you shared :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Llopis, I have meant all "known" plants and metabolites, could you recommend me any db with a coverage as high as possible?

Answer (score 3):

[PhytoMine](https://phytozome.jgi.doe.gov/phytomine/begin.do) is an InterMine interface to data from Phytozome, the Plant Comparative Genomics portal of the Department of Energy's Joint Genome Institute, which hosts 81 assembled and annotation genomes, from 78 viridiplantae species.